# Consuming SOAP based web services from Drupal (How to pass unencrypted user password)

Tags: drupal, encryption, soap, passwords

I need to call the following functions on some other portal through web service (SOAP). This functions will be called whenever a user is created/updated, change password, enroll for a course.

Following Method needs to be called.

CreateUser():

Parameters: FirstName,LoginName,Password,Email

UpdateUser():

Parameters: UserID,LoginName,FirstName,Password,ConfirmPassword,Email

My questions?
1. How do I pass unecrypted user password on event like user registration
2. Is there any module that will help me consume(call) SOAP based web services using Rules Module. Basically the moment a new user is registered or password is change these web services will be called to create or update the user on third party non-drupal based site.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: No, but I was able to do it by using the hook_user()